# nodejs & express delete session from sessionStore

Tags: node.js

I need to check whether a user has already logged in from another PC and if so terminate the previous session.

The following code does not throw any errors when it executes, however I am unable to end the first session by either calling destroy() on the session store or by deleting the session id from the session store using delete.

How can i terminate the session of a user by using the session id ?

```
function test(user_id){
  var ss = sessionStore.sessions;
  for(var sid in ss){ 
    var ses = JSON.parse(ss[sid]);
    if(ses.user_id==user_id) {
      console.log('kill:'+sid)
      delete ss[sid];
      sessionStore.destroy(sid,function(x){});  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you `console.log` the `x` value in the destroy callback ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`req.session.destroy();`

this what works in 4.x express.

So in your case do `ss[sid].destroy();`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code, this will destroy the session details of the user and logout the user..

```
if (req.session) {
        // delete session object
        req.session.destroy(function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                req.session = null;
                console.log("logout successful");
                return res.redirect('/');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I am trying to do is to logout a different user, not the current user, see my code where the user_id is provided to the function.

Comment: Are you using MongoDB? If so, you can use connect-mongo to save user ids in sessions collection. you can remove a user session from that collection using user_id